# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read a log file of log4net:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
```

and I get the Exception specified on the topic. I guess log4Net is holdin an exclusive lock on the file, but, as for example Notepad++ can read the file, I guess is technically possible to do this.

Any help?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
using (FileStream fs = 
    new FileStream(filePath,
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
//...
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx

Your log may be write locked, so try with FileShare.ReadWrite.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It still says that the file is used by another process. Any idea why?

Comment: Oddly, this fixes my problem, even though the conflicting access is a StreamReader.

Answer (score 17):

Try to add the FileShare option, see if that helps:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

EDIT: corrected code, not `FileShare.Read` but `FileShare.ReadWrite` does the trick (as Guillaume showed as well). The reason: *you want to open your file and allow others to read and write it at the same time.*